# Make an array from the changed values - Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

My array on display

```
[
 {"name":"Domain  Users","access":null},
 {"name":"Domain  Guests","access":null},
 {"name":"Domain  Controllers","access":null},
 {"name":"Domain  Admins","access":null},
 {"name":"teachers","access":"1"},
 {"name":"SparkUsers","access":null}
]
```

My array is an observable array and I am foreaching through it via template.

On each click, access value changes (null - 0 - 1)

What I am trying to do is, when an access value changes, I want to be able to grab only the changed ones ( {"name": ..., "access": ...} pair for the changed "access") instead of the whole array. I do not have a clue on how to do it though.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your HTML also, or even better, could you create a JsFiddle demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I got curious and came up with this solution (see http://jsfiddle.net/rhp_74/qTema/)
In a nutshell, what you probably want to do is make `access` a `ko.observable` so you can subscribe to change events and react appropiately.

HTML

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <a href="#" data-bind="text: name, click: changeAccess"></a>
    &nbsp;
    Access: <span data-bind="text:access"></span><br />
</div>
<div data-bind="with: selected">
    <h1>Clicked On</h1>
    Name: <span data-bind="text: name"></span> <br/>
    Access: <span data-bind="text: access"></span> <br/>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var raw =  [
       {"name":"Domain  Users","access":null},
       {"name":"Domain  Guests","access":null},
       {"name":"Domain  Controllers","access":null},
       {"name":"Domain  Admins","access":null},
       {"name":"teachers","access":"1"},
       {"name":"SparkUsers","access":null}
   ];

   function ItemViewModel(item) {
       var self = this;

       this.name = item.name;
       this.access = ko.observable(item.access);
       this.changeAccess = function() {
           self.access(
               this.access() == "0" ? "1" : 
                   this.access() == "1" ? null : "0");
       };
   };

   function App() {

       var self = this;

       this.selected = ko.observable(null);
       this.items = ko.observableArray();

       for(var i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
           var item = new ItemViewModel(raw[i]);
           item.access.subscribe(function() {
               self.selected(this);
           }.bind(item));
           this.items.push(item);
       }
   };

   var app = new App();

   ko.applyBindings(app);
```